# How do I install tools, packages on Linux 3.0.8 armv7l?

Tags: linux, package-management, arm, node.js

### Environment

- FriendlyArm Mini210s
- Linux 3.0.8 armv7l

On the board:

```
 # uname -a
 Linux 3.0.8-FriendlyARM #76 PREEMPT Thu Aug 21 16:53:31 CEST 2014 armv7l unknown
```

I need to install development & networking tools such as `ssh` and `build-essential` ... `node.js`

How is this done?

See I am used to work with Desktop distributions, so I am little lost on how to get started.

Can I install `apt-get` or `yum`? Should I? They must be special versions, where do I get them?

Comment: You cannot install either of those tools, is likely the case. Take a look at this document: http://www.friendlyarm.net/dl.php?file=S3C2440_install_linux.pdf and also I'm assuming you downloaded the prebuilt Linux binaries from here: http://www.friendlyarm.net/downloads#download

Comment: I am taking over the work from someone. So I don't know how it built his image, but I am guessing you are right. So do I need to install from RPMs? special RPMs for Armv7l? (going through the doc now! thanks for that one)

Comment: No there are no RPMs. Don't think of this as a regular Linux distro, it is much more bare bones than that. So you'll likely have to do everything manually. This is little more than a Linux kernel + busybox + libraries, nothing more.

Comment: Yep I got it. I need to cross-compile everything from source and prepare an image. Cheer!